# Cordova app stops working after replacing SHA-1 cert with SHA-2 cert on server side

Tags: android, cordova, ssl, ssl-certificate, sha2

after replacing SHA-1 cert with a new SHA-2 cert (server side), our cordova android app (ios still working) does not work anymore.
Meaning that the https requests fail somehow (on all devices available to us - Android 4.3;4.4;5.1 - Cyanogenmod 4.4.4).

Strangely this only happens if the app is installed per apk. If installed per adb everything works perfect.

We check everything we could think of (e.g. chain, https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html, etc.).
Nothing indicates a problem.

Both certificates are form Comodo (PositiveSSL).

Every hint will be much appreciated!

ps.: we switched back to a new SHA-1 cert but this will only work for 30 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seemed that the problem was the cert itself. After being in contact with the supplier we could resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have a very similar problem and it's driving me nuts! What was wrong with the cert if you don't mind me asking? I'm hoping we have the same issue!

Comment: Hey, we just switched the issuer from Comodo (PositiveSSL) to GeoTrust (RapidSSL). That oddly enough solved it.

Comment: Oh, now that is interesting. We also have a Comodo certificate that isn't working, although it is replacing an existing Comodo certificate that does work! Maybe we just need to try another provider. Thanks for the info